# truffle compile not really compiling anything: "I'm new"

Tags: json, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, truffle

I've just started learning BlockChain Dev from an NftMarketPlace building course on unity and I stumbled on my first problem way sooner than I thought. i did what the guy asked me do, but i when i hit truffle compile in my terminal all it says is

```
Compiling your contracts...

===========================

\\\> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
```

also there is no build folder created.

all the files are here:

[the link to the github repo](https://github.com/deauthe/blockChainDevProblem1.git)

i tried to compile the sol files but it did'nt happen, instead i think they never got recognized

Answer (score 0):

check the [truffle docs](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration/#contracts_directory)

in `trufle-config.js` you have this

```
 contract_directory: './src/contracts/',
```

it should be `contracts_directory`